# Java Scan An Object

Tags: java, class, object

I have a method that uses an object from the class Region, because this method is used by another method i need to scan that object so i can apply the method.

```
public void changeBusinessPermitTile(Region region){
        if(getRegion()==null) {
            Region i;
            Scanner scanner = null;
            try {
                System.out.print("Please insert the region: ");
                scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                i = scanner.//this is the missing part
                setRegion(i);
            } finally {
                if (scanner!=null) 
                    scanner.close();
            }
        }
}
```

So what i want is that when i write for example

```
Region region1 = new Region(Landscape.COAST);
Region region2 = new Region(Landscape.HILL);
Region region3 = new Region(Landscape.MOUNTAIN);
```

that method should be able to scan when i write region1, region2 or region3

Comment: You will want to avoid closing a Scanner that has been initialized on `System.in` unless your entire program is done using `System.in`.

Comment: so i only suppress the warning `Resource leak: 'scanner' is never closed`?

Comment: Also your code looks like it may be mixing business logic with user interface. The two should be kept in separate classes if at all possible.

Comment: `"so i only suppress the warning Resource leak: 'scanner' is never closed?"` -- no, don't recreate the Scanner where you use it. Create only one Scanner object for the application, and close it when the application is done. If you keep your UI code separate from your logic code, this is much easier to accomplish.

Comment: ok, so if i follow your advice and create another class used only to put all the input my game needs i create a scanner field and then on each method i should close it?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. No, you never close a Scanner based on System.in until the entire program is done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may read `Landscape` as `String` and initialize the instance like

```
 Region r = new Region(Landscape.valueOf(scanner.nextLine()));
```

In addition, you could create your own small pool (`Map<String, Region>`), where keeps `Region` instances. It will look like [Flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).

```
if (map.get(scanner.nextLine()) == null) {
    // create an instance and put it in the map
} else {
    // return old value from the map
}
```

Comment: but wouldn't that create a new Region object?, because once i've created region1,region2 and region3 every time i use that method i'm supposed to only use one of those objects.

Comment: @mpz, when you write`"region1"`, you expect to get `new Region(Landscape.COAST)`?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko if you mean each time it should create a new region coast then no, what i want is to ble able to leave the argument region on null `changeBusinessPermitTile(null)`and then it should ask me to insert it, so i could write region1, region2 or region3 as input.

Comment: @mpz, you want to create these 3 instances once and then just return them?

Comment: yes, because when i create a region i add a lot of field values, so if i create a new instance i wouldn't have those field values anymore

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I understand your question, in that in a nutshell, you're trying to associate a Region with a String. If so, then the canonical solution is to use a Map, such as by using the abstract type, `Map<String, Region>`, which you'd likely instantiate as a `HashMap<String, Region>`. You would then fill the Map with String/Region pairs using the `put(String key, Region value)` method, and then get a Region based on the key String using the map's `get(String key)` method.

I still have concerns over your overall program design, but that's a separate issue.

For example:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RegionFun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Region> regionMap = new HashMap<>();
        regionMap.put("coast", new Region(Landscape.COAST));
        regionMap.put("Hill", new Region(Landscape.HILL));
        regionMap.put("mountain", new Region(Landscape.MOUNTAIN));

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter location of region: ");
        String input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();

        Region region = regionMap.get(input);

        System.out.println("Selected Region: " + region);
    }
}

enum Landscape {
    COAST, HILL, MOUNTAIN
}

class Region {
    private Landscape landscape;

    public Region(Landscape landscape) {
        this.landscape = landscape;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Region [landscape=" + landscape + "]";
    }
}
```